# Moduli of complex integrals and upper bound

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $C$ denote the line segment from $z=i$ to $z=1$. By observing that of all the points on that line segment, the midpoint is the closest to the origin, show that

$$|\int_{C}\frac{dz}{z^4}| \leq4(2)^{0.5}$$

Approach: Clearly $L=2^{0.5}$, but I am having a hard time finding $M$. The book just shows cases in which the contour is a circle , so we always have something like $|z|=c$, but in this case the contour is a line. I was thinking to get that M we have to paramatrize the this line aNd take the moduli, so in this case $$z(t)=t-(t-1)i$$, but this case the modulo of this function doesn't give me a constant.

..... Reading the material one more time I noticed I have to find a constant M such that $z(t) \leq M$ for $0 \leq t \leq 1$. Is that correct?

Comment: Hint: Find the value of $|1/z^4|=1/|z|^4$ for the mid-point in question.

Answer (score 1):

Geometrically, it can be seen the the closest point to the origin on the triangle (which is of course the midpoint) will in fact be the minimal value of $|z|$. However, this will of course be the maximum for $1/|z|$ and in turn the maximum of $1/|z|^4$. By straightforward calculation, the midpoint had norm $1/\sqrt{2}$, and thus the inequality follows immediately.

By the work of your post, the constant $M$ you are trying to find it precisely $\sqrt{2}^4 = 4$, and we are done.

Comment: Ummm, I think I got it. Conceptually we are trying to find a constant M such that $\frac{1}{z^4} \leq M$. $|1| \leq 1$ and now we have to find and upper P bound for $|z^4| \geq P$, but we clearly have an upper bound for $|z|$ which is in fact the distance from the origin to the mid-point. Let denote this distance by $t$, so $|z| \geq t$, so $|z|^4 \geq t^4$

Comment: Probably just a typo, but note that $1/z^4 \leq M$ has no meaning in the complex plane, you want to maximize $1/|z|^4$. I would suggest drawing this in the complex plane if you haven't already, because it becomes much more clear. You will basically see that the complex number $z_m$ corresponding to the midpoint on your segment must have the smallest modulus, since it is the closest to the origin.

Comment: yes sorry $|\frac{1}{z^4}| \leq M$